# window.addEventListener in a conditional

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm running into an odd problem where window.addEventListener (or window.attachEvent) doesn't seem to be firing when called from within an if/else block.  For example, say I have the following html and javascript files:

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" CONTENT="no-store">
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tst = new Tester();

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", tst.onloadFunc, false);
    console.log("addEventListener in conditional");
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent(window.attachEvent("onload", tst.onloadFunc));
    console.log("addEvent in conditional");
} 
//window.addEventListener("load", tst.onLoadFunc, false);
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

test.js

```
function Tester() {
    this.onLoadFunc = function() {
        console.log("in Tester");
    } 
}
```

If I visit test.html and fire up a javascript inspector, I see "addEventListener in conditional" logged.  However, I do **not** see "in Tester" logged.

Now, if I uncomment the addEventListener line outside of the if/else, I do see "in Tester" logged.

Can someone explain why this is happening?  Is there any way around it or a better way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: You have a typo: `txt.onloadFunc` in the first example is missing a capitalized 'L', as well as in your `window.attachEvent` call.

Comment: `window.attachEvent(window.attachEvent("onload", tst.onloadFunc));` looks wrong as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

You should pass tst.onLoadFunc instead of tst.onloadFunc as an argument to addEventListener.

Comment: Arg, thanks for catching that...nothing like a typo to start the day.

Answer (score 2):

Your capitalization of `onLoadFunc` is wrong in the conditional `window.addEventListener` call.